# npm err! code 1 in the vscode during installation for Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to execute a code I have downloaded from the github in my machine. I have set the ambient for angular in the vscode and the issue npm ERR! code 1 is keep showing up.
I've tried some alternative during a search in the stack overflow with no success..
bellow is the erro I hope some one is familiar with the solution.

```
PS C:\Users\cborge14\Documents\L&D\pdAcademy\pdacademy-frontend-angular> npm i
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\cborge14\Documents\L&D\pdAcademy\pdacademy-frontend-angular\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! 'D\pdAcademy\pdacademy-frontend-angular\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\cborge14\Documents\node-gyp-build\bin.js'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cborge14\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-06T22_29_27_170Z-debug-0.log
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem, first remove the `node_modules` folder if it exists in your project solutions then clear you npm cash. you could do that with command or just remove the `npm-cache` folder at this directory:

```
C:\Users\'your-user-name'\AppData\Roaming
```

or

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\local
```

After these steps, the npm command should work properly.

Comment: I've removed the node_cache and ran the npm install... same message error... it did not work for me so far...

Comment: did you use npm i --force after delete npm-cache folders?

Comment: first try I used the npm install... so after your comments I have deleted the node_cache and tried the npm i --force... same issue has happened...

Comment: Gents, I could be able to temporally fix the issue, at least I could run the application.

Comment: I have created manually the folder node_module 
in the application folder and when the VS code got stuck prior to the 
error message I have forced it to close. Doing that I could be able to
keep as much as possible node_module files that were deleted after install
crush. Once I've done that I ran ng serve and I could access the web page.
I know it is not a fix but I'd like to let you guys know that I could 
temporally solve the issue. I have tried everything that my knowledge  could reach including reinstall the VScode. A friend has downloaded the same package and did not have problem.

Comment: So I'm assuming it is some file or folder installed in my machine that is causing the issue..